# respond_with Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using the respond_with and respond_to methods for the first time. My controller file looks like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.post = @post
    @comment.user = current_user
    authorize @post
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was saved."
      redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the comment. Please try again."
      redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

    authorize @comment
    if @comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment couldn't be deleted. Try again."
    end
  end

  respond_with(@comment) do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to [post.topic, @post] }
  end

private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

I'm getting the error, "RoutingError: Undefined Method respond_with".

I've googled "respond_with", and in the Rails Guides it says that I need a gem called 'responders', which makes sense. When I try to add that, though, I run into trouble; apparently, 'responders' needs another gem, 'railties', which rails requires a different version of that gem. My rails has been working just fine without 'railties', at least until now.

Does anyone know whether I actually need 'responders' in the first place, or what else might be causing my error message, or which version of 'railties' I should install, if any?

Thanks!

Comment: The responders gem is only for Rails 4.x, which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0.9.

Comment: Then I don't know why it's complaining about the gems, you're probably with one or another locked on a specific version on your Gemfile.lock.

Comment: But Eliot Sykes already found the real issue, I didn't notice respond_with was outside the method!

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `respond_with...` code to be within the `destroy` method.